# How to find the sum of the remainders of a number modulo all the perfect powers less than it?

Tags: number-theory, summation, perfect-powers

Perfect powers are numbers of the form $ x^y $ where $x\geq1$ and $y>1$. For example, perfect powers are $\{1, 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, \cdots \}$.
If $n$ is a natural number, then we denote by $P(n)$ the set of perfect powers $\le n$.

We further denote by $n\bmod x$ the remainder of division of a natural number $n$ by another natural number $x>0$. This will be an integer in the range $[0,x-1]$.

> Let's fix a natural number $n$. Can we say anything about the sum?
>   $$S(n):=\sum_{p\in P(n)} (n\bmod p)$$

In other words, the sum has one term for each perfect power $p\le n$.

I guess there are some correlations between $ n\bmod2 $, $ n\bmod 2^2 $, $ n\bmod 2^3 $ etc, but couldn't figure out a way to do it without traversing the entire list of numbers.

Comment: Is $ n\%p $ the same as $n\bmod p$?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: So for $n=5$ the sum is $5\bmod 1+5\bmod 4$? What should this be? Do we take this modulo something in the end? Could you clarify this with the example $n=5$?

Comment: For $ n=5 $, the sum is $ 5\%1 + 5\%4 = 0 + 1 = 1 $

Comment: No, $5\bmod 1$ need not be $0$. It can be any integer. And $5\bmod 4$ is $1$ or $5$ or $9$ or $13$ etc. You cannot add two classes like $\overline{0}+\overline{1}$.

Comment: I agree, multiple values are possible in this case. But here just the minimum value of the class will work fine.

Comment: Well, $5\bmod 4$ also contains $-3,-7,-11,...$ which has no minimum. Nonnegative we could take, but I don't know what this should mean. Why would you want to sum this up?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $p$ runs over all perfect power less than $n$ , starting with $4,8,9,\cdots$, but maybe there is a better way to edit the question

Comment: Pokemon, I tried to make the question unambiguos. Please check that this is what you intended. Most importantly, that $n$ stays the same throughout the summation, but $p$ varies?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, this is what I intended. Can you please suggest a way to do this?